# PHP fetch into multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to use bind_result and while-fetch to fetch a set of data into a 2d array, I have searched through the internet for solution, but it doesn't work as expected. I am not sure what goes wrong in the code after few hours debugging. Appreciate if anyone can helps to detect the blind spot.

Scenario:

I have a table as below:

```
tbl_team
teamname    id      name    gender
team1       1       John    Male
team1       2       Kelly   Female
team1       3       Chan    Male
team2       1       Jordan  Male
... etc
```

I created a function to query these base on teamname.

```
<?php 
function queryteam ($team)
{
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select id, name, gender from tbl_team where teamname = ?");
   if($stmt)
  {
     $stmt->bind_param('s',$team);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->store_result();
     $stmt->bind_result($team_member['id'],$team_member['name'],$team_member['gender']);
     $team = array();
     while($stmt->fetch())
     {
       //echo implode(" - ", $team_member)."<br>"; //debug purpose
       $team[] = $team_member;
     }
     $stmt->close();
     return $team;
  }
}
?>
```

Then I have a part of code will call this function and print the result on the screen:

```
<?php
  $team_array = queryteam( "team1");
  FOR($i = 0, $count=count($team_array);$i<$count;$i++)
  {
     echo "Team1 Members as below:<br>";
     echo implode(" - ",$team_array[$i])."<br>";
  }
?>
```

Expected result will be like:

```
Team1 Members as below:
1 - John - Male
2 - Kelly - Female
3 - Chan - Male
```

But in fact I am getting the result as below:

```
Team1 Members as below:
3 - Chan - Male
3 - Chan - Male
3 - Chan - Male
```

The query returns the result is correct as I tried to echo during the while(fetch), but the problem is, inside the while, the array is overridden with the latest fetch result.

Thanks in advance for all the helps.

**edit
I have edited the script and tested as commented by Geo:

```
<?php 
  function queryteam ($team)
  {
    ....
       $team = array();
       while($stmt->fetch())
       {
         //echo implode(" - ", $team_member)."<br>"; //debug purpose
         $team[] = $team_member;
         echo "within FETCH: <br>";
         print_r($team); echo "<br>";
       }
       $stmt->close();
       return $team;
    }
  }
  $team_array = queryteam( "team1");
  echo "Function returned:<br>";
  print_r($team_array); echo "<br>";
  ?>
```

I got the result as below:

```
within FETCH:
Array([0]=>Array([id]=>1 [name]=>John [gender]=>Male))
Array([0]=>Array([id]=>2 [name]=>Kelly [gender]=>Female) [1]=>Array([id]=>2 [name]=>Kelly [gender]=>Female))
Array([0]=>Array([id]=>3 [name]=>Chan [gender]=>Male) [1]=>Array([id]=>3 [name]=>Chan [gender]=>Male) [2]=>Array([id]=>3 [name]=>Chan [gender]=>Male))
Function returned:
Array([0]=>Array([id]=>3 [name]=>Chan [gender]=>Male) [1]=>Array([id]=>3 [name]=>Chan [gender]=>Male) [2]=>Array([id]=>3 [name]=>Chan [gender]=>Male))
Array([0]=>Array([id]=>3 [name]=>Chan [gender]=>Male) [1]=>Array([id]=>3 [name]=>Chan [gender]=>Male) [2]=>Array([id]=>3 [name]=>Chan [gender]=>Male))
Array([0]=>Array([id]=>3 [name]=>Chan [gender]=>Male) [1]=>Array([id]=>3 [name]=>Chan [gender]=>Male) [2]=>Array([id]=>3 [name]=>Chan [gender]=>Male))
```

Comment: Are you sure that's what it's doing? Have you done a `print_r` of the array to make sure that the data in it is as expected?

Comment: Hi Geo, the returned array has 3 rows inside, and 3 rows of them are overridden by the latest fetch from query. Can you share more details on print_r? in fact i am quite new to PHP. Thanks for your help!

Comment: all three array elements are references to the same variable.. use fetch instead of bind results to create new arrays for each iteration

Comment: in `bind_result()` use a different variable for each result e.g. `bind_result($id, $name, $gender)`

Comment: Hi Orangepill, noted, will try this out. update in moment.

Comment: Hi evans, thanks! this works like a charm! Thanks to Orangepill and evans_murithi! I will add the answer in below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Orangepill and evans_murithi!

I never thought that it was caused by the bind_result

Modified as below:

```
<?php 
function queryteam ($team)
{
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select id, name, gender from tbl_team where teamname = ?");
   if($stmt)
  {
     $stmt->bind_param('s',$team);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->store_result();

     //change this part
     //$stmt->bind_result($team_member['id'],$team_member['name'],$team_member['gender']);
     $stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $gender);
     /*******/

     $team = array();
     while($stmt->fetch())
     {
       $team_member = array();
       $team_member['id'] = $id;
       $team_member['name'] = $name;
       $team_member['gender'] = $gender;
       //echo implode(" - ", $team_member)."<br>"; //debug purpose
       $team[] = $team_member;
     }
     $stmt->close();
     return $team;
  }
}
?>
```